# Copying adt-bundle from win7 to win8

Tags: android, windows, eclipse-adt

I am trying to copy my adt-bundle dir from win7 to win8, including sdk. Did anyone try this before? is it a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far so good. I copied the ADT-bundle (eclipse + adt + sdk) and my old workspace, had to change dependencies in a couple projects to the new paths and now everything works as expected.